# C# - require an interface on a base class but only the implementations in derived classes

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, abstraction

I'm trying to create a base class that provides a good amount of re-usable functionality to many classes that will derive from it. By providing this functionality, I'd like to also require the derived classes to implement certain methods as well, i.e. implement an interface. However, I don't want to explicitly tell the derived classes they need to implement the interface, I want that requirement to be defined in the base class. So basically, once a class inherits from the base, it gets functionality, but also the requirement to implement additional methods itself. Here's what I want, and I'm honestly not sure if this is possible:

```
public interface IExtraStuff {
  bool test();
}

public class BaseControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IExtraStuff {

  public bool foo(){
    return true;
  }

  // I don't actually want to implement the test() method in this
  // class but I want any class that derives from this to implement it.

}

MyUserControl1 : BaseControl {

  // this.foo() can be used here

  // according to IExtraStuff from the BaseControl, I need to implement test() here

}
```

Basically I don't want to have to define `MyUserControl1` as:

```
MyUserControl1 : BaseControl, IExtraStuff
```

I want it to automatically require the interface once it inherits the extra functionality from `BaseControl`.

If this is not possible, let me know and that's fine. I just don't know enough about it. As I have it currently written, it compiles, and I feel like I should get a compile error since `test()` is not defined in `MyUserControl1`.

**UPDATE**

I've modified my base class to be abstract (I had done this prior to posting to SO) but I actually can build the project without implementing the abstract method, that's really why I started to ask this question. The code below builds for me which I'm confused about:

```
public interface IExtraStuff {
  bool test();
}

public abstract class BaseControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IExtraStuff {

  public abstract bool test();

  public bool foo(){
    return true;
  }

}

MyUserControl1 : BaseControl {

  // this.foo() can be used here

  // I can build without implementing test() here!

}
```

**UPDATE 2: problem solved**

It turns out I had an issue in my solution build setup and the project does not build unless I implement the abstract method from the base (now). This was error on my part in Visual Studio, not an error in the class architecture. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: I assume that MyUserControl1 : BaseControl is a public class? Because what is posted shouldn't compile?

Comment: Yes, I was tying in a sample to be simple and missed that keyword. The overall error was in my project setup in Visual Studio and my build. My fault, not an issue with the architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use abstract methods?

```
public abstract class BaseControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IExtraStuff { 

  public bool foo(){ 
    return true; 
  } 

  public abstract bool test();  
}
```

See for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(VS.71).aspx

**Edit**
Adding dervied class impl.

```
public class MyCustomControl : BaseControl { 

  public override bool test()
  {
    //Add Code...
  }  
}
```

Comment: you'll have to label the class as abstract as well, otherwise you'll get compile errors

Comment: I actually tried this and in my derived class I am not required to define `test()` and when I type in `test()` in a code block it gets it from the base class as if it has a defined body, which it does not. *reading that article now...*

Comment: @Mark if you have properly labeled the class as abstract (not sure what your timing was with Jeff's edit), then you would have gotten build errors telling you that your concrete class needs to implement the abstract method test()

Comment: Thanks again Matt, was just adding the impl of the derived class before adding the comment :D

Comment: @Matt, I did label the class as abstract but I did not define an implementation for `test()` in my derived class and I can build the project! This is what prompted me to ask this question, I'm really confused why it builds! I keep expecting a compile-time error until I implement that method.

Answer (score 2):

That's what abstract classes and methods are for

```
public abstract class BaseControl : IExtraStuff
{
   public abstract bool test();
}
```

Note, the class needs to be marked as abstract also

Answer (score 1):

If you make BaseControl an abstract class, you can omit the interface members, and so, force the implementation in child classes.

Comment: You can't *omit* the interface members, but you can leave them unimplemented by marking them abstract. It's not quite the same thing.